# Can we use AD level features(like conditional access policy and device management, etc) in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Currently, we are using Azure AD B2C in one of our website and we want to enable the conditional access policy for our users. I want to know whether we can able to use the conditional access policy and other AD features for Azure AD B2C users or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, conditional access is an Azure AD Premium feature, so it isn't available for Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Is there any way to implement/achieve the conditional access policy and identity protection features in Azure AD B2C?